# Как обнулить переменную которая находиться в Fragment из Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

**Fragment**

```
public class ScoreboardFragmentOne extends Fragment {

int i;

/*.....*/


btnSocer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
    socer_textview2.setText("" + i);
    if(i>=9 && btnSocer1 !=null){
        i =9;
        socer_textview2.setText(""+ i);
        btnSocer1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    if(i==1 && btnSocer2 != null){
        btnSocer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
        }
    });
}
```

Мне нужно обнулить переменную i. Допустим в Fragmet i = 8;. Но когда при нажатии в Activity на кнопку Refresh, должно что бы i = 0.

**Activity**

```
public class SocerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimerDialogFragment.onTextViewNum, ScoreboardFragmentOne.onSomeEventListner {



/*.....*/

refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                socer_textview2.setText("0");
                socer_textview.setText("0");
                socer_textview3.setText("0");
                socer_textview4.setText("0");
                fols_team1.setText("0");
                fols_team2.setText("0");
                timeWhenStopped = 0;
                time_value.setText("1");
                resume = false;
                time_val_bool =true;
                btnSocer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSocer3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnSocer2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnSocer5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnSocer7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSocer8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnFols2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnFols3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cmTimer.stop();
                cmTimer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


                 //тут нужно обнулять i из Fragment 



            }
        });


}
```

этот Fragment используется еще в нескольких Activity

Comment: Сделать во Fragment нужный метод и вызвать его: `scoreboardFragmentOne.renewScore()`?

Comment: @AlexKrass делал так, не работает

Comment: Видимо где-то не доделали, возможно не обновили содержание текстового поля в самом Fragment вместе с обновлением переменной и видимость. По крайней мере на том, что я вижу, этот подход должен работать.

Comment: @AlexKrass сделал та    
scoreboardFragmentOne = (ScoreboardFragmentOne).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
 scoreboardFragmentOne.renewScore();
И получилось, можете написать в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обновления фрагмента из активити достаточно в самом фрагменте определить метод, который будет отвечать за нужные действия.

```
public class ScoreboardFragmentOne extends Fragment {

    int i;

    /* ..... */

    public void renewScore(){
        i = 0;
        /* другие операции по необходимости */
    }
}
```

А дальше его вызвать из активити, когда он нужен.

```
public class SocerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ... {

    /* ..... */

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* ..... */
            scoreboardFragmentOne = (ScoreboardFragmentOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment); 
            scoreboardFragmentOne.renewScore();
        }
    });
}
```